# Static table view with uitableviewclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I added a Table View Controller in to my storyboard. I changed the content to Static Cells and added some rows with section. After that I connect the Table View Controller with a UITableViewController Class and build the app. But the problem i, it won't work. Why? Can I not use a UITableViewController class for a Static Table View?

It looks like that:

[image]

Error code looks like that:

Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:6245
2015-06-24 19:26:02.356 test[55871:1795263] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier first - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: *it won't work* isn't a sufficiently detailed description of the problem to let us help you. And yes, you can certainly use UITableViewController with static tables.

Comment: what is the error message? or do the cells just disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static tableviews do not implement delegate methods : numberOfSections & numberOfRows

Comment: Yes, UITableViewController subclasses by default adds these delegates in code with 0 section and 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

> After that I connect the Table View Controller with a UITableViewController Class and build the app.

If you're creating an instance of `UITableViewController` in your code and also adding a "Table View Controller" to your storyboard, then you've got TWO table view controllers. If that's the case, then you have one more than you need, and the one you're looking at isn't configured correctly.